# Retrieving Dropdown List Data From Web Service - Model vs Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

ASP.NET MVC 4 | C# | .NET 4.5 | Razor

I have web services that return data for dropdown lists. This data gets stored in my model and then displayed by my view. Currently I'm making the web service calls in the controller and assigning the data to the model before it gets passed to the view.

I'm wondering if this is a good setup, or if I should place my web service calls in my model? Are there any best practices guidelines on web service calls? Should they be called strictly from the controller, or does it not matter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's a significant performance impact, the ideal logical setup would be that this takes place in the model.

The usual quote is, "Keep your controllers light and your models heavy."  (I don't know who first said that.)

The controller shouldn't be populating the model.  It should just get an instance of the model and supply it to the view.  At most it should do some routing logic (determining which view to send, or to respond with a redirect, etc.) and basically, well, controlling the interaction between the models and the views/UI.

So instead of something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = WidgetFactory.Create();
    model.SomeProperty = DataService.GetPropertyInfo();
    return View(model);
}
```

You should be doing this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = WidgetFactory.Create();
    return View(model);
}
```

with this on the model:

```
public SomeType SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        return DataService.GetPropertyInfo();
    }
}
```

or perhaps this, if there's overhead in fetching the data:

```
private SomeType _someProperty = null;
public SomeType SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        if (_someProperty == null)
            _someProperty = DataService.GetPropertyInfo();
        return _someProperty;
    }
}
```

This has the added benefit that `SomeProperty` becomes immutable as far as the model is concerned.  Since it's never modifying that data and only ever supplying it, there's no reason to have a setter for that property that a controller can use.

The idea here is that the model is as self-contained and self-sufficient as possible.  Or as encapsulated as possible.  It represents the business concept in and of itself.  If part of that business concept is data which exists on another system, the model encapsulates that.  It's not the controller's responsibility to know physically where a `Widget` gets its data for `SomeProperty`.  It just knows that a `Widget` exposes that data.  Where the `Widget` gets it is up to the `Widget`.

Comment: Nice approach and I like the solution too. But I could not understand what you meant by "Unless there's a significant performance impact"?

Comment: @Raj: I can't think of an example at the moment, but in general there are sometimes instances anywhere in software design where the physical limitations of the system force us to compromise on otherwise good logical design choices.  Basically, if you can't think of a reason either, then you're not facing one and don't need to worry about it.  When a performance issue comes up, it's usually obvious :)

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense. I think I'm going to place it in the getter as you demonstrated in your last example.

Answer (score 1):

There are few of ways doing as long as if you Controller is leaner and testable, you can pick any approach you like. Note that you also want to make sure your view model simple and stupid. You don't want put much behaviour in view model.

Your View Model can be simple as this. I would prefer not having much behavior or calls to services in my view model.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CustomerList { get; set; }
}
```

I would create a simple extension method or a helper class that converts my domain data to DropDownList  view model i.e SelectListItem

```
internal static class ListHelper
{
    internal static MyViewModel ConvertToMyViewModel(this IEnumerable<Customer> customers)
    {
        //Assign customers to CustomerList;
        //MyViewModel.CustomerList
        return new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

Note that you might later find yourself repeating similar code whenever you want to covert. You can always create generic version, so methods are reusable. But the key point is your extension/helper method helps you to convert. It only does the conversions, but nothing else.

Inject your Service into the Controller. Take the advanage of your faviourite dipendency injection framework if you use any. Your controller is testable.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebService _webServiceInfo;

    public HomeController(IWebService webServiceInfo) {
        _webServiceInfo = webServiceInfo;
    }

    public ActionResult Index() {
        var customers = _webServiceInfo.GetCustomers();
        var viewModel = customers.ConvertToMyViewModel();

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```